# display elements from db

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

In order to create a pagination, I will have to store all the paths to image in the database. I created my database as following:

```
id(auto increment) int250
name varchar 250
link text
type varchar(250)
category int(50)
```

The name and the types are not quite relevant in this moment. 
    I would like to figure out on how to display the elements from my database. In order to make it easier(not sure about the paths yet) I have stored in the link column a http image.
    IF i vardump it, I get everything with an array.
    My code:

```
<?php
if (DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()) {
$pics = DB::table('pictures')
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
->get();
 var_dump($pics);
 }

?>

My result:


array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#182 (5) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["name"]=> string(1) "2" ["link"]=> string(66) "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg" ["type"]=> string(3) "pic" ["category"]=> int(1) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#183 (5) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(1) "2" ["link"]=> string(66) "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg" ["type"]=> string(3) "pic" ["category"]=> int(1) } [2]=> object(stdClass)#184 (5) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(4) "test" ["link"]=> string(66) "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg" ["type"]=> string(5) "test1" ["category"]=> int(1) } }
```

How do I get the pictures displayed as pictures?

Sorry, I'm quite a beginner in programming, doing my best to learn.
    I'm trying to get this done, because I finished a website, and all the pictures were hardcoded. Now I must implement pagination, and in order to do that, the best way would be to store the images link, and display them with limit 10; for example.

Any help would be great!

EDIT:
Controler:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

Comment: I also think that it should be something like this:  echo "<tr><td><img src='".$pics->link."'></td>";

Comment: Since you are using Laravel, you could use a [Blade template](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) to display the pictures. And you may already know this, but [pagination is built in.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination) You should be able to use `paginate(10)` instead of `get()`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes you're right @Don'tPanic :)

Comment: ok, but how do I display the links?! it does not work. PS, I stored the links in the link column. also it would be great if I could display all elements, and add the pagination.

Comment: Can i see your controller?

Comment: I have not modified the controller at all. Everything was hardcoded, i'm just starting to implement the backend, and I suck a this.

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}

Comment: Can you add this in your question?

Comment: done, I have edited the main posted, and I added the controller there

Comment: Why do you use abstract classes?

Comment: That was written by default..

Answer (score 1):

If your using laravel, in the method your using from your controller add this code

```
    $pictures = Picture::paginate(20);

    return view('view_name', ['pictures' => $pictures]);
```

Then in your view add

```
@foreach ($pictures as $pic)
   <img src="{{$pic->link}}" />
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($pics as $pica){
if($pica->type!=='pic'){continue;/*not a pic.. ignore?*/}
echo '<img src="'.htmlentities($pica->link, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true).'" />';

}
```

Comment: this works. what if i'm using in the database links to the path? this would solve my issue!